# Asana-like platform with offline desktop access

Tags: web-apps, osx, offline, project-management, calendar

I'm looking for a platform like Asana or, less so, Trello, but the catch is it really needs to be able to be used offline. Both of those platforms have various wrappers enabling 'desktop' use, but neither work offline.

All I really want is the ability to manage multiple task lists and sublists and schedule activities to be done in a calendar - all packaged up.

I'm surprised I haven't found something that does all of this (and that doesn't cost what Omnifocus costs).

I need offline as I work remotely a lot and am frequently away from internet access.

PS: I asked Asana support whether they're looking at an offline desktop app and they said no - maybe in the future, but essentially no.

Edit: Forgot to add - am on Mac OSX - on El Capitan. And free is great but paid is OK if it gets the job done!

Comment: Sorry! Mac OSX - on El Capitan. And free is great but paid is OK if it gets the job done! Thanks for prompting me to clarify.

Comment: no problem, we can probably clean up these comments:)